# How can I unlock Vault-88 quest items with console commands?

Tags: pc, fallout-4

"**This post may contain what can be considered spoilers!**"

I have Fallout4 with all DLCs installed on my PC. When I started Vault-88 quest and I saw the ghoul overseer ordering me around. I didn't like it and I killed her.

A few days ago, I asked my friend to see his vault. In his screenshots, I noticed a fixed bike, a slot machine and eye exam. I found out that these items will be unlocked when you complete vault-88 quests.

I built my whole vault and completed many quests. I can't go back to the save before I kill the ghoul overseer. Is there any way to unlock those items with console commands? Maybe there are mods that unlock them, but I prefer to play vanilla game so I didn't install mods on my game.

Comment: If you know that some sentences are spoilers, use the spoiler container to hide them.

Comment: "I don't think there's a universal command, the only way I can thik of doing it is setting the stage where those workshop items unlock in their respect quests (or setting the quest to finished)." https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/1500126447391994300/

Comment: "*set DLC06AllowVaultAnywhere to 1* this unlock the vault tec structures, generators, guard posts and what not in settlement workshop. it does NOT unlock the phorptor, power cycle and such." https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=783510481

Comment: @Mazura it does't unlock those items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Power_to_the_People_(Vault-Tec_Workshop)

> This bug is usually caused by obtaining the Vault-Tec prototypes note that unlocks the settlement happiness items. This note is carried by Valery Barstow and can be looted from her corpse. Alternatively, it can be obtained by using the scrapall command on the workshop, in which it will be added. Retrieving this note from the workshop will immediately break the quest as if you obtained it by killing Barstow. To fix this, the following console commands may be used:

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockSlotMachineExperimental to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockSlotMachine to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockSodaStationExperimental to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockSodaStation to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockPhoropterExperimental to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockPhoropter to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockPowerbikeExperimental to 0

> Set DLC06RecipeUnlockPowerbike to 1

> This should enable the Prototype Powerbike in the Special listing while removing the final products from the Resources > Vault-Tec menu.

Check the *Vault* : *Resources* tab first. If the quest is running, it should still be in *Special*.

> After completing the quest, the Power Cycle 1000 can be mass produced. **It is located on the Vault tab under Resources**.

---

*Resurrect* the overseer.

*setstage DLC06MQ02 200*
(possibly the wrong quest or the wrong stage. All of this is unverified. '200' is stage 2 of https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Better_Living_Underground)

Do the quests.

Comment: I tried this. it didn't work.

Comment: @BlackCrystal - Did you loot her body? I walked in there, killed her, failed the quest, looted her, and now I can build those four things. I looked into resetting a quest but I couldn't get it to work : https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/3565190-can-someone-please-help-me-reset-this-quest/ - note, I had to *enable* her after *resurrect* because she was 'missing'. - Or just do, *player.additem [xx]0053DA* ; (Vault-Tec prototype book) `help prototype 4`

Comment: let me try this